# Problemas con la fecha en consultas SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Tengo una aplicación en Java que lanza una consulta SQL que vendria a ser mas o menos asi:

```
select INT.* 
from TABLA1 INT 
LEFT JOIN TABLA2 SEG on INT.CAMPOA = SEG.CAMPOA 
WHERE INT.CODIGO = '00000000000XXX' AND INT.F_HASTA <= '20/09/2022';
```

El problema es que existiendo datos en esa `F_HASTA` para la fecha indicada, no los esta mostrando, es decir, esta realizando la consulta como si fuera estrictamente `INT.F_HASTA < '20/09/2022'`.

Alguien podría aclararme porque se puede producir esto o si la consulta en si esta incorrecta?

Gracias

Comment: Qué DBMS estás usando? Las funciones de fecha y hora y la forma de almacenarlas tienen algunas diferencias.

Comment: Uso una BBDD Oracle y trabajo con Oracle Developer

Comment: Prueba con `trunc(INT.F_HASTA) <= '20/09/2022'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te muestra hasta la fecha que le indicas, solo que por defecto la hora que busca de ese día son las 00:00:00, o sea que si quieres ver un registro de ese día, que no sea a las 20/09/2022 00:00:00, y que busque en todo el día completo, debes poner por ejemplo:

```
select INT.* 
from TABLA1 INT 
LEFT JOIN TABLA2 SEG on INT.CAMPOA = SEG.CAMPOA 
WHERE INT.CODIGO = '00000000000XXX' 
AND INT.F_HASTA <= TO_DATE( '20/09/2022 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

También he encontrado [info relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34216915/7321009) que te podría ayudar.

Comment: Pon en tu respuesta qué dice la "info relacionada". El enlace podría caer...

Comment: @Jackson-Quintero "ósea" = _de los huesos_, "o sea" = _es decir_ ;)

Comment: @padaleiana si es verdad tiene razón